# How to create bottom sheet effect which cover full activity when user scrolls up

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog

As shown in Image, When user click on list a bottom sheet comes up 
and when user scroll up that bottom sheet cover full page just like an activity with toolbar.

How to achieve this ??
What is logic behind the scene ??

[image: UI presentation of dialog behaviors on scroll up]

Answer (score 3):

First question:

> How to achieve this ??

Using a custom Behavior (it extends from CoordinatorLayout.Behavior) for a Persistent BottomSheet or modal one.

Second question:

> What is logic behind the scene ??

The logic is:
It has some states (like google maps app) hidden, collapsed, dragging, anchor_point, expanded.
When its reaching expanded state it use another modified Behavior to show you an `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

By default BottomSheetBehavior has only 3 states, you have to add a 4 state (anchor_point) that is the one that will makes it to stop in half way of Y axis.

Probably now you want to see some code. Look at this [simple example project](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior) in where you can see how to get 4 states.

pd: [this link is the most useless that I have found in all answers about this topic :(](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.co/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Answer (score 1):

The google team  recently released the Android Support Library 23.2, that adds this feature.
This is the link's post ,I hope that it's help you.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

[image]

Comment: No actually my project using Android Support Library 22.0 but I wanted to understand concept how it is getting implemented and look like exactly fragment with toolbar

Comment: You could give a look to the source code and see how they achieved it, only press CTRL + CLICK (windows) or COMAND + CLICK (mac) on the class.

Comment: I have been looking for this behavior all week and as far I can see all people just repeat the same "look at this link..." an useless one